# How do I redirect to a GET view without changing the URL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC web site, with a form on a view. The form posts back to the same action (obviously with an `[HttpPost]` attribute and a parameter for the model). Note that this is doing a traditional HTTP `POST`, not an Ajax `POST`.

The `POST` action processes the data, and I want to show the user a "Thank you" page, but using the same URL. I can do this by doing the following at the end of the `POST` version of the action...

```
return View("ThankYou");
```

However, that leaves the user's browser on a page that has been `POST`ed, meaning that if they hit the refresh button, it re`POST`s the form. I need to avoid that.

Is there a simple way of doing this? I guess I could create a whole new action, a whole new view model, populate the view model with info from the current one, then redirect to that action, passing in the new view model, but it seems like a lot of work for something that feels like it ought to be simple.

Comment: You should learn about the [Post-Direct-Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: Sounds like a job for some js script.

Comment: @GibralterTop Thanks, but shouldn't all of this be done on the server? I thought Angular was client-side stuff

Comment: @GibralterTop What? He needs to entirely change his framework just to accomplish a simple post redirect get pattern? What a wild suggestion.

Comment: @mason Am I right in thinking that Post-Direct-Get is basically what I described? Create a new view model and redirect to a new action, passing the view model? Please confirm or explain. I don't mind doing that if it's the best way to do it, it just seemed like a lot of work for somethign I expected to be easier. Thanks

Comment: @mason I edited my comment shortly after posting. But really if you just want to change what the viewer sees after clicking a button `js` is the quickest way. Probably 2 lines of code max.

Comment: @GibralterTop You're assuming AJAX is being used. This sounds like a traditional form submit.

Comment: @mason 100 ways to cut a cake.

Comment: @mason You're correct, and I edited my question to include that. Thanks for the observation. Please can you answer my question in the comment "Am I right in thinking..."

Comment: It's slightly different than what you described, because we need to redirect the client. But it will accomplish what you want. Omu's answer is an example of this, although I'd rather my `Create()` action method return a different view based on the temp data instead of having the View do that.

Comment: @mason Bit new at this, so please could you explain how I redirect the client from the controller? I thought that's what RedirectToAction did, which is why I thought what I described was RPG. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, RedirectToAction is how you perform the redirect. See Omu's answer.

Comment: @mason Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Create(CreateInput input)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid){
   // save
   TempData["created"] = true;
   return RedirectToAction("Create")
  }
  return View(input);
}
```

and in the Create view:

```
if(TempData["created"] != null){
  @<text>Thank You </text>
}else{
... the form
}
```

it can be done without tempdata but the url will change a bit (url?created=1)

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner just to return a different view rather than have the view switch what it's showing?

Comment: the important part is not changing the url that's what the OP wanted, you can put the if the controller or in the view, that's up to you

Comment: @Omu Thanks, that was exactly what I needed! As it happens, I did the `if` in the controller, as I want to keep as much logic out of the view as possible, but the concept was the same. Thanks again.